# Unable to stop NSTimer

Tags: ios, nstimer

I use this code for stopping `NSTimer`

```
[timer invalidate]
timer = nil;
```

It works fine for the first run. But, after I resume the timer with this code.

```
 timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0
                                     target:self
                                   selector:@selector(checkNewUpdates)
                                    userInfo:nil
                                    repeats:YES];
```

`NSTimer` won't stop anymore with `[timer invalidate]`

Comment: Nothing wrong with what you posted. We need more context.

Comment: I set the timer in viewdidLoad. The timer is used to check updates on the web service. I stop the timer everything the method has seen a new updates from the server, which is prompted by an alertview. The timer stops at first. But, when I try to stop it on the second time, It won't stop anymore. The alertview shows every 5 seconds.

Comment: As @SantaClaus you need to show more code.  Is `timer` an iVar? a property? a local variable?

Comment: I'd suggest putting breakpoints or log statements where you create the timers and where you `invalidate` the timers and I wager that you'll see a mismatch, where you're failing to `invalidate` the previous timer before starting the next. But there's not enough here for us to diagnose the source of that problem.

Answer (score 3):

It look like multiple instance of timer is running simultaneously. You can do one thing, before start to run a new timer, check for previous instance of timer, and if timer instance is available, then invalidate it. After this start new instance

```
if(timer)
{
  [timer invalidate];
  timer = nil;
}
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0
                                     target:self
                                   selector:@selector(checkNewUpdates)
                                    userInfo:nil
                                    repeats:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

In apple's [official document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTimer/invalidate) they said:

> You must send this message from the thread on which the timer was
>   installed. If you send this message from another thread, the input
>   source associated with the timer may not be removed from its run loop,
>   which could prevent the thread from exiting properly.

If your timer is running on main thread, do this:

```
[timer performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(invalidate) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
```

If it is on any other thread, lets call the thread myThread, then do this:

```
[timer performSelector:@selector(invalidate) onThread:myThread withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```

Hope this helps.. :)

Comment: It is also worth noting that `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval` schedules the timer on the current run loop.

Answer (score 0):

Just invalidate the timer inside the selector that fires.  That will ensure you have a pointer to the correct timer (which is probably why your `invalidate` call isn't working:

```
 timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0
                                     target:self
                                   selector:@selector(checkNewUpdates:)
                                    userInfo:nil
                                    repeats:YES];
```

Note the colon after `checkNewUpdates:`

Then, in your checkNewUpdates: method, do something like this:

```
- (void)checkNewUpdates:(NSTimer*)timer
{
    // do somehting

    // Then, check if the criteria for stopping the timer has been met, and invalidate it here.
    if( self.shouldStopTimer )  // made up variable, use your own criteria.
    {
        [timer invalidate];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this doesnt answer your question per-se;

Can I suggest using polling mechanism instead of a timer? Ive had a world of trouble with `NSTimers` in the past and polling was a good alternative. Ive made a simple one below.

```
- (void) doPoll {
    // do logic here

    if (shoudStop) { 
       return;
    }

    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, X * NSEC_PER_SEC)), 
                                                  dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self doPoll];
    });
}
```

This is just a simple example, it does not stop `retain cycles` If you choose to try this, Yours should.
Hope it helps.